# Twig checking for object within object

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a voting system in a Symfony application and I'm using the Twig Engine. I want to be able to do something like this within my template to show the user they've already voted (think StackOverflow orange arrows).

```
<div class="vote {% if entry.votes.user == loggedinuser %}already-voted{% endif %}">Vote</a>
```

The problem with this is though, each entry can have multiple votes (so `votes` is actually a `PersistentCollection`. I know I could do this with PHP or even by looping through each of the `votes.user`, but thats messy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a method to your entity so that your template would remain clean and the business logic would be tucked away in the entity similar to:

```
<div class="vote {% if entry.hasVoted(loggedinuser) %}already-voted{% endif %}">Vote</a>
```

Comment: This was, in the end, probably the best solution that I found.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can use the [in](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#containment-operator) operator instead of iterating over each vote instance.</strike> According to Twig documentation the *in* filter will perform a containment test on strings, arrays, or objects implementing the Traversable interface.

Try the following:

```
<div class="vote {% if loggedinuser in entry.votes.user %}already-voted{% endif %}">Vote</a>
```

**EDIT:**

It seems like the *in* operator doesn´t work with an instance inside a Collection. I'm afraid you will need to iterate over each vote to check whether both users match or not.

In order to prevent things getting messy you could use a [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can't use `in` because votes doesn't have a method/property `user`, gives me: `Method "user" for object "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" does not exist`

Comment: if I use `user in entry.votes` (which should technically work), nothing enters the condition.